# HttpPost Imagen en Xamarin Forms & PHP

Tags: php, c#, laravel, imagen, xamarin

Tengo el problema de que mi imagen, o bien mi file, no lo recibe mi método de servidor en **PHP**, ¿alguien sabe a que se debe?, Me devuelve error status 500.

```
private MediaFile _image;
private string idx;
private async void AgregarAutobtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    lblError.Text = "Agregando su auto";
    try {
        var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;
        if (current != NetworkAccess.Internet) {
            await DisplayAlert("Sin linea", "Active sus datos o su wifi para agregar un auto.", "OK");
        }
        StringContent hex = new StringContent(colorhex.ToString());
        StringContent id_usuario = new StringContent(idx);
        StringContent placas = new StringContent(placasx);
        StringContent modelo = new StringContent(modelox);
        StringContent ann = new StringContent(annx);
        StringContent marca = new StringContent(marcax);
        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(new StreamContent(_image.GetStream()), "imagen");
        content.Add(id_usuario, "id_usuario");
        content.Add(placas, "placas");
        content.Add(modelo, "modelo");
        content.Add(ann, "ann");
        content.Add(marca, "marca");
        content.Add(hex, "color");
        content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
        var url = "http://miapi:3/auto/guardar";
        var responseMsg = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
        // ... subir a internet
        switch (responseMsg.StatusCode) {
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
            await DisplayAlert("error", "error status 500 InternalServerError", "ok");
            lblError.Text = "hubo un error status 500 ";
            break;
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
            lblError.Text = "hubo un error status 400 ";
            await DisplayAlert("error", "error status 400 Unauthorized", "ok");
            break;
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
            await DisplayAlert("error", "error status 403  ", "ok");
            lblError.Text = "hubo un error status 403 ";
            break;
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
            await DisplayAlert("error", "error status 404  ", "ok");
            lblError.Text = "hubo un error status 404 ";
            break;
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK:
            Cator.IsRunning = false;
            Cator.IsVisible = false;
            string xjson = await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            await DisplayAlert("error", "yeah status 200 : " + xjson, "ok");
            break;
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestEntityTooLarge:
            await DisplayAlert("error", "error status 413  ", "ok");
            lblError.Text = "hubo un error status 413 ";
            break;
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout:
            await DisplayAlert("error", "error status 408  ", "ok");
            lblError.Text = "hubo un error status 408 ";
            break;
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
            await DisplayAlert("error", "yeah status 401 Unauthorized", "ok");
            break;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Error : " + ex.ToString(), "OK");
        Cator.IsRunning = false;
        Cator.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi función que recibe los datos en el servidor:

```
public function guardar(Request $request) {
    $cat_autos = new Autos();
    $cat_autos->id_usuario = $request->Input("id_usuario");
    $cat_autos->placas = $request->Input("placas");
    $cat_autos->modelo = $request->Input("modelo");
    $cat_autos->ann = $request->Input("ann");
    $cat_autos->marca = $request->Input("marca");
    $cat_autos->color = $request->Input("color");
    $foto = $request->file('imagen');
    //$cat_autos->imagen = $request->Input("imagen");
    if(!empty($foto)){
        $ext =  $request->file('imagen')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time().'.'.$ext;
        $upload = $request->file('imagen')->storeAs(
            'uploads/autos', $filename
        );  
        if($upload){
            $cat_autos->imagen = $request->Input("imagen");
        }
    }       
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        if ($cat_autos->save()) {
            $msg = ['status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Se ha guardado correctamente'];
        }
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
        $msg = ['status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'No se pudo guardar correctamente, por favor consulte con el administrador del sistema.', 'exception' => $ex->getMessage()];
        return response()->json($msg, 400);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
        $msg = ['status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'No se pudo guardar correctamente, por favor consulte con el administrador del sistema.', 'exception' => $ex->getMessage()];
        return response()->json($msg, 400);
    } finally {
        DB::commit();
    }
    return response()->json($msg);
}
```

Este es mi intento por **Postman** y obtengo todo bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el problema es que no ves tu foto capturada en el contron Image?

Comment: quiero mandar la imagen y mandar en el mismo content un string, un string fecha ... etc y quiero poder confirmar que mi `_image` contiene en efecto la imagen

Comment: Coloca la parte del backend que consideres que puede ser de utilidad para reproducir tu escenario... por favor... Gracias :')

Comment: No conozco php, no puedo ayudarte pero en mi caso cuando me daba error 500 algo mal estaba en mi servicio web y respondia mal. Seguramente es como le pasas los parametros. Que recibe tu servicio un json?

Comment: @RamiroBarone hola , pues como puedes ver por postman si me recibe la imagen por tanto lo que está pasando es que no le estoy enviando bien el file, pero no entiendo como o porque :s

Comment: Probaste mandar con HttpClient?

Comment: @RamiroBarone si aquí mero ` var responseMsg = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);`

Comment: te recibe json el web service?

Comment: @RamiroBarone la funcion que recibe mi peticion desde el xamarin esta arriba posteada, el problema es que no consigo enviar desde xamarin la imagen como un file, si omito el file , el request se ejecuta sin problemas, y aso cp,p esta justo ahora si lo mando por post man con todo y file igual me devuelve un status 200

Comment: Si recibes el código 500 algo debe haber en el log del servidor.

Comment: Revisa el valor de `$request->file('imagen')->getErrorMessage()`